# multiple different protobuf messages in a socket

Tags: sockets, protocol-buffers

I use protobuf with my c++ server. But I have a problem with multiple different protobuf messages in a socket
I define many proto messages, such as

```
message SdkHGetRet {
  required int32 opcode = 1;
  required bytes value = 2;
}

message SdkHPut {
  required bytes table = 1;
  required bytes hname = 2;
  required bytes key = 3;
  required bytes value = 4;
  optional int32 writesrc = 5 [default = 0];
}

message SdkSet {
  required bytes table = 1;
  required bytes key = 2;
  required bytes value = 3;
  optional int32 writesrc = 4 [default = 0];
}

message SdkSetRet {
  required bool status = 1;
  optional string master = 2;
}

message SdkInvalidOperation {
  required int32 what = 1;
  required bytes why = 2;
}
....
```

So every time I send the message by socket, I will add 8 bytes, 4 for the total socket len, 4 for the opcode, opcode mean the message type.

So in the server side, I receive the message, I read the first 4 byte, and I got the message's length, then I will read another 4 bytes to get the message's type, at last I read the message's length bytes. Then I will use message type to method map ( such as 404 => "sdkset", 405 => "sdksetret") to decode the message.

I find this way work well, but I wonder is there any elegance way to identify the message without the 4 byte message type.
I have read the message history, one method is add the entire message in a big message, like this way

```
message BigMessage
{
enum Type { sdkset = 0, sdksetred = 1}
require Type t = 1,
optional  string key = 2,
...
}
```

Since I have more than 40 types of message, I think this way may affect performance, and in my opinion, this way looks ugly.

So can you give me any good suggestion..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Protobuf v2.6.0 introduced [the `oneof` keyword](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto?hl=en#oneof) for this. Example:

```
message BigMessage {
  oneof message {
    SdkHGetRet hgetret = 1;
    SdkHPut hput = 2;
    ...
  }
}
```

`oneof` ensures that exactly one of the fields is set, and lets you `switch()` on which one.

Note that even before Protobuf 2.6.0, the best solution would have been a series of optional fields, perhaps with an enum to specify which one is set:

```
message BigMessage {
  enum Type { HGETRET = 0, HPUT = 1, ... }
  required Type t = 1;
  optional SdkHGetRet hgetret = 2;
  optional SdkHPut hput = 3;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. My consideration here is that whether this way may affect performance? And if this way work well, I think it is a good way to delete the 4 byte which stand for the message's type.

Comment: @baotiao I don't think it will hurt performance, but if you're worried you should benchmark. You may want to consider reusing one message object to parse each message (which will be much easier when there's only one type) -- this usually improves performance a lot, since it reduces allocations.

Comment: Yes, using one message object to parse each message will simply my job, I will test the new way to use protobuf. But I find some other project use protobuf the same way as me. such as  https://github.com/mhaberler/machinetalk-protobuf/blob/master/proto/object.proto   Do you think we both using protobuf in the wrong way?

Comment: @baotiao - Yes, I highly recommend using `oneof` and not hand-rolling message headers.